# Can we upgrade a managed package programmatically

Tags: managed-package

We do have a managed package and we are making changes in package very frequently. Right now, whenever we make any change, we are providing Subscriber a new package link; then subscribers are upgrading the package manually.

Now, we do not want subscriber to experience this..just thinking solution like we can build an admin page (visualforce page) where Subscriber will just click a button and package will get upgraded.

Is it possible?

If this is not possible then is there any workaround to update a lightning component which is part of managed package from any admin page (this admin vf page would belong to same managed package) in subscriber org?

I found an article to install package through API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_api_introduction.htm) but I am not sure how it would work? Or how should I start? Can we use this Andrew's solution : https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Answer (score 3):

For packages where you're just patching fixes quickly, use a [patch organization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/isv4_1_quickstart.htm). You can push these changes to an org transparently without approval. This only works if you're not adding or removing component, etc. Otherwise, you should be pushing updates to your subscribers; you don't want to necessarily have your subscribers having to install patches constantly. There's no real, guaranteed way to install updates automatically besides patches. Upgrades are intentionally limited to admin approvals so that subscribers don't get caught out in the open with a broken org.

Comment: Thanks Brian!  but I am not getting option to create a Patch Organization as mentioned here on 3rd step.

Comment: You have to create a patch organization. Unfortunately, my experience in this area is non-existent. Perhaps you'll get a better answer from someone else, though.

Comment: Thanks!  I found an article to install package through API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_api_introduction.htm) but I am not sure how it would work? Or how should I start? Can we use this Andrew's solution : https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Comment: @αΥβ I don't think you should ordinarily be installing new package versions without admin permission.

Comment: What if admin of that org process it via custom visualforce page button?

Comment: @αΥβ Like I said, you should consider patch orgs.